# ASP.NET MVC, Entity Framework : Display Windows Username in _Layout

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I enabled Windows authentication in the `web.config` file but how can I display the current Active Directory authenticated user in the `_Layout.cshtml` page?

Keep in mind this is not .NET Core, it is .NET 4.7.1 using Entity Framework. I'm not trying to impersonate anyone. Everywhere I look on Google turns up only antiquated .NET 2.0 posts or .NET Core answers to this question and usually involves impersonation, none of which apply to this.

Right now I just have the standard default layout page. I tried adding:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity
```

I haven't published this to IIS yet so that's out of the picture at the moment, but will be publishing it there in the near future.

Comment: Did you tried `@HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name`?

Comment: The normal way of getting the current user's username will work just fine, assuming Windows auth is enabled and Anonymous auth is disabled.

Comment: What is "the normal way"?  I tried @HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name and got zilch.

Comment: @Nathan, Is Anonymous authentication disabled ?

Comment: Not explicitly that I am aware of. I tried finding the Web.config tag for that but it literally exists nowhere on the internet. There's an iis page out there explaining the anonymousAuthentication tag but it doesn't even tell you how to set it to disabled in the Web.config. I literally typed "how to disable anonymous authentication in web.config" into Google and got everything BUT how to do that.

Comment: I also tried adding <anonymousAuthentication enabled="false" /> into the web config and it says that's not a valid tag.

Comment: How did you enable Windows authentication?

Comment: In the System.Web section of the Web.config file. I was able to make `@HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name` work after installing IIS Windows Authentication and disabling anonymous in IIS manager, but I can only see it when running from IIS, not from start without debugging. Also it's showing the wrong username, it's showing my personal admin account for anyone who hits the IIS site. Nothing is running as this account, not even the app pool.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using IISExpress in VS. Please refer to [this blog](https://www.danesparza.net/2014/09/using-windows-authentication-with-iisexpress/) regarding how to make win auth work on IISExpress.